# When attempting to upgrade to latest Hapi.js (9.x) we get: Error: Unknown handler: directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

Just tried updating to the latest version of [Hapi.js](http://hapijs.com/) but getting error for `directory` handler ...

We are using hapi.js to serve a `directory` in our static-server.js 
see: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-tdd/blob/5b132bfe5e1787b684ff44eadaf8b53438449323/static-server.js#L3

The `directory` handler worked fine in hapi 8.x but in 9.0.1 we get the error:

```
Error: Unknown handler: directory
```

We've tried searching on the Hapi.js Route API: http://hapijs.com/api#route-handler 
but have not found the `directory` handler ... was it removed in the latest release? The "old" version of Hapi.js had: http://hapijs.com/api/8.8.1#route-handler

full stack trace: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-tdd/issues/22

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [inert](https://github.com/hapijs/inert) plugin needs to be included manually in version 9 (release notes: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/2682). Add it as a plugin using server.register

follow the instructions on https://www.npmjs.com/package/inert#examples
e.g:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Inert = require('inert');
var Path = require('path');
var server = new Hapi.Server();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
server.register(Inert, function () {
  server.connection({ port: port });
  server.route( {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    handler: {
      directory: { path: Path.normalize(__dirname + '/') }
    }
  });
  server.start(function() { console.log('Visit: http://127.0.0.1:' +port)   });
});
```

Comment: I've *just* finished adding this answer to the release notes thread... ;-) https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/2682#issuecomment-131256862 but since you made the effort to answer here! answer accepted and upvoted! thanks!

Comment: Updated the example. The `register()` method is asynchronous, you shouldn't ignore the callback. You will run into problems if you attempt to start the server before plugins are registered. You should also check for errors.